# whats does am start -n command do in android shell

Tags: android, shell, android-shell

I am trying to know, what does this command do when I write it in the terminal for android?
and here is an example

am start -n com.whatsapp/com.whatsapp.HomeActivity

Thanks

Comment: did you read the result of `am`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is `please read the doc for me`

Comment: why? I am just asking what does the command do, 
what is it for?
I just read it in a blog and I didn't understand it !
I don't want to know the result, just why do we use it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it'll tell am (Activity manager) to start an Activity.

See here for more detailed info:
    http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#shellcommands